# Wrong number of items and non match shape of passed values when to merge dtype(O) and 'float64' array to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm expected a dataframe with one 111 columns and one rows, which name of columns is from `column1` and the first row is `column2`

Here's my data `column1`

```
Index(['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3',
       ...
       'Col 110', 'Col 111'],
      dtype='object', length=111)
```

Here's my data `column2`

```
array([0.06308672, 0.02825317, 0.05428668, 0.00368413, 0.00282469,
      ...
       0.00129729])
```

Addtional information

`column1.shape` resulted `(111,)`

`column1.dtype` resulted `dtype('float64')`

`column2.shape` resulted `(111,)`

`column2.dtype` resulted `dtype('O')`

Here's what I did

`pd.DataFrame(column2, columns = column1)`

And the result is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1661                 blocks = [
-> 1662                     make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
   1663                 ]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype)
   2721 
-> 2722     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   2723 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    129         if self._validate_ndim and self.ndim and len(self.mgr_locs) != len(self.values):
--> 130             raise ValueError(
    131                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 111

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-226-5a79c428cd8e> in <module>
----> 1 pd.DataFrame(column2, columns = column1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    495                 mgr = init_dict({data.name: data}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    496             else:
--> 497                 mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    498 
    499         # For data is list-like, or Iterable (will consume into list)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    232         block_values = [values]
    233 
--> 234     return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
    235 
    236 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1670         blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]
   1671         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1672         raise construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   1673 
   1674 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (111, 1), indices imply (111, 111)
```

Comment: You provide the dataframe with a single array, so 111 elements, which are 111 elements in 1 column, therefore 111,1. Now you provide a list of columns, which seem to be also 111 elements, but columns are on the top of the dataframe. So your provided series lets pandas guess that you want to provide 111 columns of 111 values (111,111), or: 12.321 values, which you didn't provide, therefore the error. If you provide the "columns" as index=columns. It should propably work.

Comment: Can you suggest the sintax `pd.DataFrame(column2, columns = column1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the column in the parameter `index`, specifying it in `columns` is throwing that error.Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(column2 , index = column1)
```

The above code stores `column1` as `index`, if you don't want to do that and have columns names, please try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(column2 , index = column1).reset_index()
df.columns = ['column1', 'column2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need bracket around `column2`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([column2], columns = column1)
```

```
print(df)

      Col 1     Col 2     Col 3     Col 4     Col 5     Col 6    Col 7  ...   Col 105   Col 106   Col 107   Col 108   Col 109   Col 110   Col 111
0  0.933107  0.932057  0.681201  0.421621  0.159919  0.333099  0.79994  ...  0.540713  0.882822  0.372501  0.632753  0.684067  0.105904  0.492178
```